# searchcpan.actvestate.com is redirecting to search.cpan.org

Tags: perl, cpan, activestate

Apologies if I understood anything wrong for perl repository.

I am using activestate perl on my windos for development.

To look for any missing module I used to search it at http://searchcpan.activestate.com site. This used to give me the information about the distribution and repository (activestate, trouchelle, bribes etc) and various version of perl supporting this module.

Now it seems that this site is redirecting to search.cpan.org. I am missing few information here like the distribution to use.

Please let me to know how to find the repository name in such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's located on http://code.activestate.com/ppm/ now.
BTW, http://searchcpan.activestate.com/ could at least redirect to http://metacpan.org/ :)